# AWS Lambda Function Import Environmental Variable Google API Service Account Json Decode Error

Tags: python, aws-lambda, environment-variables, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have a web scraping script that scrapes data and writes into a google spreadsheet. I am using the service account feature on gspread. I would like to deploy it as an AWS Lambda Function to have the script run once a day.

This is what a a part of my code looks like.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import gspread
from datetime import datetime
import time
from decouple import config
import json
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    print(os.environ["TEST"])
    
    gc = gspread.service_account_from_dict(json.loads(os.environ["SERVICE_TOKEN_JSON"]))
   
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': 'Function executed successfully'
    }
```

However, I receive a JSONDecodeError. My SERVICE_TOKEN_JSON environmental variable is a string in json format such as `'{"test":"value","test2":"value2"}'`

The TEST environmental variable seems to go through. I can't seem to find the issue.

It works on my local machine but on AWS Lambda it does not work.

When I test it, it returns this error:

```
`Test Event Name
(unsaved) test event

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)",
  "errorType": "JSONDecodeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 19, in lambda_handler\n    gc = gspread.service_account_from_dict(json.loads(os.environ[\"SERVICE_TOKEN_JSON\"]))\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py\", line 346, in loads\n    return _default_decoder.decode(s)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py\", line 337, in decode\n    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py\", line 355, in raw_decode\n    raise JSONDecodeError(\"Expecting value\", s, err.value) from None\n"
  ]
}

Function Logs
'TEST'
[ERROR] JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 19, in lambda_handler
    gc = gspread.service_account_from_dict(json.loads(os.environ["SERVICE_TOKEN_JSON"]))
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from NoneEND `
```

Comment: Can you try printing os.environ["SERVICE_TOKEN_JSON"] before trying to parse it to json. Because from the error stack it seems that it has None value.